# Copying parallel arrays to new parallel arrays without duplicates

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing a method which takes two parallel arrays and an int size variable to keep track of the indexing. So for example

```
String[] names = new String[100]; //Partially filled array
int[] scores = new int[names.length]; //Scores for each plater
int entry = 0;

names[size] = "Bob";
scores[size] = 20;
size++;
```

The above code indicates that on my first entry in the "list" tis of Bob who has a score of 20.

I am writing a method which takes the names array, scores array, and the size variable. I must copy the information of the arrays passed on to new arrays but with the duplicate entries into one entry and their sum aligned.

So for example if there is the original list

```
Name: Bob, Score: 20
Name: Paul, Score: 30
Name: Bob, Score: 10
//Size - 3
```

So my new parallel arrays must be

```
Name: Bob, Score: 30
Name: Paul, Score 30
//Size - 2
```

I have created a method, and which does add the sum of the names, I am stuck on the process of removing the duplicates.

```
public static void totalDurations(String[] oldNames, int[] oldScores, int oldSize) {

    String[] newNames = new String[100];
    int[] newScores = new int[newNames.length];
    int newSize = 0;

    int matchPos;
    int addDuration = 0;

    String tempString = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < oldSize; i++) {

        //the find method returns the index of a string if found else it returns -1
        matchPos = find(oldNames, oldSize, 0, oldNames[i]);

        while (matchPos >= 0) {

            addDuration += oldScores[matchPos];

            // Find the next match, starting after the last one
            matchPos = find(oldNames, oldSize, matchPos + 1, oldNames[i]);

        }



        newNames[newSize] = oldNames[i];
        newScores[newSize] = addDuration;
        addDuration = 0;
        newSize++;

    }

    //Print the List
    for (int i = 0; i < newSize; i++) {
        System.out.println("Name: " + newNames[i] + ",  Score: " + newScores[i] );
    }

}
```

If I pass the entries

```
"Bob", 10
"Bob", 10
"Paul", 20
"Paul", 20
"Bob", 10
```

My output is

```
Name: Bob, Score: 30
Name: Bob, Score: 30
Name: Paul, Score: 40
Name: Paul, Score: 40
Name: Bob, Score: 30
```

So for **my main question**. What is a good algorithm I can use to copy the Name and the total score onto the new arrays **only once**. While keeping in mind that due to duplicated the new size of the list will be smaller than the old one always.

Thank you in advance.

**I want to achieve this with only arrays and conditional loops.**

Comment: [parallel-processing] has to do with multiple threads or multiple processes working cooperatively.  The "parallel arrays" discussed in this question have nothing to do with that.  Tags edited.

Comment: Don't use two aligned arrays, use `java.util.Map`s.

Answer (score 1):

Create a map using `name` as the *key* and `score` as the *value*. If you find that a `name` already exists, retrieve its value, add the current `score` to the retrieved `score`, and update it by putting the new `score` into the map.

After you've completed this over your initial `name[]` and `score[]` arrays, iterate over the Map's [`EntrySet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) and add each Name and Score into the respective new `array[]`s.

(By the way, this has nothing to do with parallel processing or multi-threading.)

Comment: Hi Keith, thank you for your response. While I would try that I am not familiar with map(s). I would like to achieve this with only arrays and loops, sorry for the parallel processing tag. I think I accidentally put it there.

Comment: I think other people are in agreement that arrays are not the correct data structure. Using them to achieve your goal is succumbing to an  "X-Y problem".

Comment: I understand it is highly in-efficient, but I must achieve this without the use of any other structure. I'm really thankful for you help! :) I will keep trying, there has got to be a way around it.

Comment: Understood. Then I would suggest implementing John Bollingers's approach. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is each time you process a new name from the input array, to scan the output array for a match.  If found, you add the score to the corresponding result score; otherwise you append the name and its score to the result arrays.  That would probably be sufficient for you.

If you want to be able to handle long arrays efficiently, however, then you need some kind of auxiliary data structure with which to efficiently locate names that have already been processed.  That could be a Map from names to result-array indices, or a Map from names to scores.  In the former case, you would proceed as described before, but consult the Map instead of scanning the output name array.  In the latter case, you would build up all the per-name scores in the Map, and then afterward populate the result arrays from the Map.

Comment: Hi John, I'm not sure what you mean. So every time I find a match from the old array I append the _name_ to the new array and the cumulative score. How would I be able to skip over the entries that I have already passed to the new arrays. This is just for minor data manipulation, I'm certain I would have to use other data structures for dealing with bigger data. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @MikeDavidson, rather than copying the arrays wholesale, you create new, empty arrays of the same size, and copy elements *one-by-one* from the old arrays.  For each name you consider from the old arrays, you scan to see whether it is already entered in the new arrays.  If you find it then you add scores, if not, you append the name and its associated score.  Note that the cost of this approach scales with the square of the number of distinct names.

Comment: Hmm, I will try this method right now and see if I'm able to achieve what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you created a new array, you could take each piece of the first array, compare it to all the elements in that array, then place unique pieces into the second array. Perhaps if one element equals another, the first element is Null. All elements not null would then be placed into the second array and printed.